# Django mptt, can I delete the default 'name' filed?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-mptt, mptt

I'm following the django-mptt tutorial,and there is a 'name' filed:

```
class Genre(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']
```

compare to my own model:

```
class Comment(MPTTModel):
    """
    评论表
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1500, unique=True,)
    nid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    news = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name='评论文章', to='News',to_field='id',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name='评论者', to='User',to_field='id',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(verbose_name='评论内容', max_length=255)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='创建时间', auto_now_add=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']
```

This 'name' filed is really bothers me, since each time I need to add this filed.

My question is can I hidden or ignore this filed?

Comment: You don't need the `name`. The `order_insertion_by` is simply how to order it, but you can remove the name and the `order_insertion_by`.

Comment: You thus can use the primary key for example over the name as `order_insertion_by`.

Comment: Thank you guys now I understand why when I deleted the name filed there was error that is because I forget to modify the order_insertion_by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you got an error when you removed the name field is because the [**`order_insertion_by`** option [readthedocs.io]](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#model-options) was referring to that field. But you can let it refer to another field. As the documentation says:

> **`order_insertion_by`**
>
> A list of field names which should define **ordering when new tree
> nodes are being inserted** or existing nodes are being reparented,
> with the most significant ordering field name first. Defaults to `[]`.
>
> It is assumed that any field identified as defining ordering will
> never be NULL in the database.

You can thus for example make use of the primary key instead:

```
class Genre(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['pk']
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, one more question,how can I limit the max deep of the recursetree?

Comment: @William: you can create a field `level` that is a `PositiveIntegerField`, but where you set a database constraint that it is less than a given value, then you register that field as `level_attr` in the `MPTTMeta`: https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#model-options

Comment: Hi friend I really appreciate your help, can you help reply me here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66465571/how-to-limit-the-max-deep-of-recursetree-in-django-mttp